# Window.OnAfterPrint not working if window.print() is called via JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Ok... so this used to work... but doesn't work anymore.

I have a html5lightbox that pops up from an asp.net page and then calls window.print() via JS.  Then after the print, the html5lightbox is closed via something similar to window.close().  However, out of nowhere, chrome will not function correctly and will the onAfterPrint event is not firing.  To simplify what is not working, I created this jsfiddle that will print once loaded, then do an alert after print dialog is closed.  Notice it works in Edge (IE) but not chrome.  What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lr7kvoh1/

```
<html>
<head></head><body>
<h1>HTML DOM Events</h1>
<h2>The afterprint Event</h2>

<p>Use the addEventListener() method to attach an "afterprint" event to the window object.</p>

<h3>Print this document!</h3>
<p><b>Tip</b>: The keyboard shortcut Ctrl+P prints a page.</p>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
window.print();
}

window.onafterprint = function () {
alert("This document is now being printed");
}

</script>


</body></html>`
```

Looked everywhere on the net.  Can't find anything.  Worked up until maybe a week ago or so...

Comment: This is on PC by the way.

Comment: I'm also facing exact same issue on latest chrome 109 version. Its working 108 version. I'm using react